# Proving that $f$ verifies $f(1-x)=-f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I'm trying to show an identity verified by a function. I have this function which is defined for all real numbers as

$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{(x+k)^{2m-1}}{(-1)^{p+k} (p-1-k)!(p+k)!}$

I would like to show that $f(1-x) = -f(x)$.

**First thing that tried:**

$
\begin{align*} 
f(1-x)
&= \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{(1-x+k)^{2m-1}}{(-1)^{p+k} (p-1-k)!(p+k)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{(-1)^{2m-1}(x-1-k)^{2m-1}}{(-1)^{p+k} (p-1-k)!(p+k)!} 
\quad \text{factoring the numerator by }(-1)^{2m-1}\\
&= -\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{(x-1-k)^{2m-1}}{(-1)^{p+k} (p-1-k)!(p+k)!}
\quad \text{reducing }(-1)^{2m-1}=-1\\
&= -\sum_{i=-p}^{-1} \frac{(x+i)^{2m-1}}{(-1)^{p-i-1} (p+i)!(p-i-1)!}
\quad \text{doing a change of variable } i = -k-1 \\
\end{align*}
$

I'm kind of stuck at this point and I don't see how to move forward with it. I think I'm not going to the optimal direction to prove that relation.

**Second thing that I am investigating:**

Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2m-1$, I could write it as a finite power series centered at $0$. So with Taylor's theorem I would have

$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{2m-1}  \frac{f^{(i)}(0) }{i!} x^{i}$.

and

$
\begin{align*} 
f(1-x) 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{2m-1}  \frac{ f^{(i)}(0) }{i!} (1-x)^{i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{2m-1}  \frac{ f^{(i)}(0) }{i!} \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{i} \binom{i}{j} (-x)^{j} \Bigg)
\quad \text{binomial expansion applied to } (1-x)^{i} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{2m-1}  \Bigg((-1)^{j}\sum_{i=j}^{2m-1} \binom{i}{j} \frac{ f^{(i)}(0) }{i!} \Bigg) x^{j}
\quad \text{changing the summation order} \sum_{i=0}^{2m-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i} \text{ to }   \sum_{j=0}^{2m-1}\sum_{i=j}^{2m-1}  \\
\end{align*}
$

So showing that $f(1-x) = -f(x)$ is equivalent to showing that
$(-1)^{j}\sum_{i=j}^{2m-1} \binom{i}{j} \frac{ f^{(i)}(0) }{i!} = - \frac{f^{(j)}(0) }{j!} $.
I think this is the more elegant way to go but I don't know if it is going to make things worse.

Any feedback ?

**EDIT : clarification of the parameters m and p** :
I forgot to mention hypothesis on the parameters $m$ and $p$. So we consider that $ 1 \leq m < p$

Comment: one approach that may pan out would be to show that $g(x) = f(x) + f(1-x)$ evaluates to zero at $2m$ suitably chosen distinct points, which would conclude $g\equiv 0$ identically.

Comment: actually, $p=2, m=1$ gives $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{2}\neq \dfrac{x}{2}= -f(1-x) = $

Comment: When $p=1$, there is only one term with $k=0$, and the function is $cx^N$ for some constants $c,N$. But $f(1-x)=c(1-x)^N$. So it seems this is false.

Comment: Hi @dezdichado, sorry for the late answer, I think the definition for $f(x)$ works fine for that case. It actually gives $f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{6}$ and you can check that $f(1-x)=-f(x)$

Comment: Hi @alex.jordan, thanks for you remark, I forgot to put hypothesis on the parameters $m$ and $p$. So actually $p>1$ and $m \geq 0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum as
$$
\eqalign{
  & f\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }
 \over {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k} \left( {p - 1 - k} \right)!\left( {p + k} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k} {{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }
 \over {\left( {p - 1 - k} \right)!\left( {p + k} \right)!}}} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad g\left( x \right) = \left( {2p - 1} \right)!f\left( x \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k}
 \left( \matrix{ 2p - 1 \cr p + k \cr}  \right)\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  \cr} 
$$

Then for the sum $g(1-x)+g(x)$ we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & g\left( {1 - x} \right) + g(x) =   \cr 
&  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr p + k \cr}  \right)\left( {1 - x + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  +   \cr 
  &  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr p + k \cr}  \right)\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2m - 1} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1}
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k} \left( \matrix{ 2p - 1 \cr  p + k \cr}  \right)
\left( {x - k - 1} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  +   \cr 
  &  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k}
 \left( \matrix{ 2p - 1 \cr   p + k \cr}  \right)\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2m - 1} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p - 1 - k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr p - 1 - k \cr}  \right)\left( {x - p + p - 1 - k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  +   \cr 
  &  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,p + k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr p + k \cr}  \right)\left( {x - p + p + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr k \cr}  \right)\left( {x - p + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  +   \cr 
  &  + \sum\limits_{k = p}^{2p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr k \cr}  \right)\left( {x - p + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2p - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k}
 \left( \matrix{2p - 1 \cr k \cr}  \right)\left( {x - p + k} \right)^{\,2m - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2p - 1} \Delta ^{\,2p - 1} \left( {x - p} \right)^{\,2m - 1}  = 0 
\quad \;\left| {\,1 \le m < p} \right. \cr}
$$
and that is the $2p-1$-th finite difference of a polynomial of degree $2m-1$
which is null if $ m < p$

Comment: Wow, sir your solution is a pure masterclass. I was definitely not looking toward the right direction !

Comment: thanks for the appreciation, but note that I corrected the range for $m,p$ : the degree of the polynomial ($2m-1$) shall be non-negative

Comment: I am actually looking for a course note on n-th order finite difference methods. I am not fully aware of the theory behind it. So is there some book or publication that I should look at ?

Comment: well you may start from [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) and in particular the Newton's series. Then if you are interested to go in depth, a magnificent and clear explanation (on this as well as other many topics) is given in the renowned "*Concrete Mathematics*"

Comment: Thank you so much !